# Get All node from fancytree plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I am trying to got list of all node from tree, when click button outside tree.
I got list of all selected node from tree, but having problem with got list of all node from tree.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.del', function () {
    var selKeys = $.map($('#tree1111').fancytree('getTree').getSelectedNodes(), function (node) {
        return node;
    });
});
```

I try this but not working

```
var allKeys = $.map($('#tree1111').fancytree('getTree'), function (node) {
    return node;
});

$.each(allKeys, function (event, data) {
alert(data.key)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to access the `source` option.

If the tree is modified dynamically, you need to recover the children of the root node, and get only the properties you need. You have a [lot of possible ways to do it](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html).

```js
var source = [
    {title: "Node 1", key: "1"},
    {title: "Folder 2", key: "2", folder: true, children: [
      {title: "Node 2.1", key: "3"},
      {title: "Node 2.2", key: "4"}
    ]}
  ];

$('#tree').fancytree({
  source: source
  });

// Get the tree
var tree = $('#tree').fancytree('getTree');

// Dynamically add new node
var folder2 = tree.findFirst('Folder 2');
folder2.addNode({title:'New node'});

// original data
var source = tree.options.source;
$('#original').html(JSON.stringify(source,null,2));


// get the tree nodes
var root = tree.getRootNode();
var nodes = root.children;
console.log(root);
console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.fancytree/2.15.0/skin-win8/ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.fancytree/2.15.0/jquery.fancytree-all.js"></script>


<div id="tree"></div>

<b>Original data</b>
<pre id="original"></pre>

<b>Data recovered from modified tree:</b>
Please, see the console. It cannot be directly converted to JSON because it has circular references (child to parent)
```

Comment: Did you mean: $('#tree1111').fancytree('getTree')

Comment: I try this but not workingvar 
allKeys = $.map($('#tree1111').fancytree('getTree'), function (data) {
                            return data;
                        });
                        alert(allKeys.node);

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
var allKeys = $.map($('#tree1111').fancytree('getRootNode').getChildren(), function (node) {
        return node;
    });

$.each(allKeys, function (event, data) {
alert(data.key)
});
```